# Tomcat sometimes responding with 403 when login with Keycloak and sometimes not

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I have 2 apps (Spring Boot and Spring MVC) both of them are deployed in Tocmcat,as

```
localhost:9595/bootapp/
```

and

```
localhost:9595/mvcapp/
```

I've registered both of them as Keycloak client:

```
my_client
```

I have 2 users userA with role (MVC_USER,BOOT_USER) and userB with roles(BOOT_USER)

1.To register boot app i used this configs in my application.properties:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://10.60.6.34:8282/auth
keycloak.realm=IAP
keycloak.resource=my_client
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
```

and here's my security config class:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
}

//keycloakConfigResolver: this defines that we want to use the Spring Boot properties file support instead of the default keycloak.json
@Bean
public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
    return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
}

@Bean
@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(buildSessionRegistry());
}

@Bean
protected SessionRegistry buildSessionRegistry() {
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user").hasRole("BOOT_USER")
            .antMatchers("/main").hasRole("uma_authorization");
}

@Autowired
public KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory;
@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public KeycloakRestTemplate keycloakRestTemplate(){
    return new KeycloakRestTemplate(keycloakClientRequestFactory);
}


}`
```

2. To register mvcapp i added this to META-INF/context.xml file:

   `<Context>
   <Valve className="org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve"/>
   </Context>`

2.1. added keycloak.json to WEB-INF:

```
{
 "realm": "IAP",
 "auth-server-url": "http://10.60.6.34:8282/auth",
 "resource": "my_app",
 "public-client": true,
 "confidential-port": 0,
 "principal-attribute":"preferred_username"
}
```

2.2.And added web.xml to WEB-INF with the following content:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">



<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>NSI</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>MVC_USER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>


<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>this is ignored currently</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>MVC_USER</role-name>
</security-role>
```

My landing page is in bootapp, so i have main.jsp file with link which redirects to mvcapp.

**MY PROBLEM IS:**

for example i type:

localhost:9595/bootapp

Keycloak's login page appears. I log in with userB (which has only BOOT_USER role) and landing page main.jsp from bootapp appears. When i try to redirect to mvc app by clicking the link, Tomcat throws me 403 error as expected, because userB hasn't got MVC_USER role. Good!

Then, when i type this to url line in browser:

http://localhost:9595/bootapp/sso/logout

i logout as expected.

**BUT**

When i re-login with userA, who has both(USER_MVC and USER_BOOT) roles, i still can see main.jsp BUT when i try to visit

```
http://localhost:9595/mvcapp/
```

Tomcat throws 403 ! Even if userA has the required role (USER_MVC).

By the way:

If i open new incognito window, and log in with userA **first** (not with userB as i did before), i have an access to both bootapp and mvcapp and after log out and log in again with userB (who shouldn't access to mvcapp) i also have access to both bootapp and mvcapp.

It seems like i have to send some kind of token or something to mvcapp, but what? And how? But if so,then how the user can assess mvcapp when login with userA? (I'm newbee in all that auth stuff)

It's been awhile since i've been trying to find a solution, but i couldn't. Please help!

Comment: Is there any reason for you to be using the same client for both apps? Keep in mind you can (and should) use two different clients and use realms roles instead (even though I don't know if this might solve your issue).

Comment: @XtremeBiker Hi, Xtreme Biker! Actually initially i was using 2 different clients for my apps, but i faced same problem: When i log out from one app using:  `request.logout()`  , Tomcat logges out from that particular app, but the second one still remains logged in. I couldn't find any way to provide Single Log Out via Keycloak. And it seems like more Java/Tomcat based issue rather than Keycloak's.

Comment: Did you try with `/sso/logout` instead?

Comment: @Xtreme Biker Do you mean just typing `localhost:9090/myapp/sso/logout`? Yes i tried, this approach also logges out from only that particular app. For example if i log in with the user who hasn't got an access to the resource i get 403, then after i type `localhost:9090/myapp/sso/logout` i log out and if i log in with the user who HAS an access to the resource i still get 403. If i open new incognito window and log in with the user who HAS access, i can see the secured resource, but if i log out and log in with the user who HASn't got an access i also can see the secured page.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I've also tried to log out like this: `http://auth-server/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=encodedRedirectUri` . Here i faced the following problem: Yes, It loges out from all apps, BUT if i log in again and try `http://auth-server/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=encodedRedirectUri` again, it's not working - user is not logging out...

Comment: You're configuring your security in both Java and web.xml. I would rather go with pure java config and don't use web.xml. They might be conflicting each other.

Comment: @XtremeBiker My second app is pure Spring MVC (no boot), and i'm wondering if i could use KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation there because in tutorial they use spring boot based dependencies and stuff. What i'm doing now is: putting all jsp's in seperate app and securing them with Keycloak. And in backend controllers of other apps i check if current user is able to work with them. Is it a good choice?

Comment: Don't think you need to do that. Just have all your stuff in one app and use the Spring Security adapter for it (write all your configuration in java). Otherwise you're leaving your MVC endpoints unprotected. You don't need Spring Boot to work with the Spring SEcurity adapter.

Comment: @XtremeBiker By "one app" you mean one war file, am i right?

Comment: Sure ;-)))))))))

Comment: @XtremeBiker Ok, i will try! Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest little changes. I am not sure what is the problem. But, you can try these and feedback please.

Try to change your keycloak clients "Access Type" to "confidential", you use this setting as "public"

your sso property file includes =>

```
keycloak.public-client=true
```

when you changed to "confidential", you must change your sso config like that (this is for boot application. Same way, you need to change for mvc app.) =>

```
keycloak.realm=IAP
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://10.60.6.34:8282/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.resource=my_client
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
keycloak.credentials.secret= /* your client secret you will reach this under 
                               "instalation tab" of IAP client
```

Try to remove "JSESSIONID" when your server logout, for boot application you can add this code block to your SecurityConfig class (configure method)

```
.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
.invalidateHttpSession(true)
```

=>

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests() 
    .....
    .....
    .and().logout().logoutUrl("*log out url*")
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .....
    .....
}
```